# Complex, yet simple crafting system model

Tags: game-design

I'm working on some arcade shooter/slasher, and the main logline is "Kick'em with everything you want". There's not so many enemies in GDD, main focus is on tons of weapons and gadgets to cause mayhem.
To get weapon, you need to craft it, and now crafting system looks simple, like:

1) You got three slots for weapon parts (like A, B, C)
2) You collect misc weapon parts, and when you got atleast one for every slot, you can craft a weapon (for example, if you got A1, B1, B2, B3 and C1, you can craft such models - A1B1C1, A1B2C1, A1B3C1)

As for me, this crafting system is too simple, because weapon parts will just fall from the top of screen, often enough. That's why I'm thinking about adding some more crafting system levels, like resources (collect 10 scrap pieces to make part A1 or C3), etc.

My question is:
How can i add some more complex, still simple, transparent levels in crafting system?

upd. For example, in Minecraft or Terraria, first 5-10 crafting recipies quite transparent and simple IMHO. But then it turns into huge mess to understand, how to craft this or that (for example, fishing rod)

upd. Okay, somehow i've figured out mechanics like this:
1) Player gather resources (while playing game, automatic gathering from loot)
2) When there's enough resources to craft some weapon part, dedicated icon flashes, so player can craft weapon part in one click (automatic crafting)
3) Having several weapon parts, player can adjust different parts to create weapon (manual crafting)

I think, this will be complex and simple enough, now over-weighted by to many buttons and receipes, still, enough of freedom and manual creativity, trying to mix this and that.

Comment: This is pretty open-ended and is likely just going to generate a bunch of opinions and ideas rather than a concrete answer.

Comment: if you want it simple you can just try to create something like any MMO's crafting system. Basically you learn a recipe (or I guess maybe you already know it), select it from the list, and hit the go button. Then either there is a cool down until you get the item or it just magically appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like your approach of adding levels points in the right direction. I one implemented a similiar system with generic crafting parts.

Like a sword need a *hilt*, a *core* and a *blade* / a gun needs a *handle*, a *barrel* and a *muzzle*. Each of this **components** is defined by **materials**, like the hilt need 1 *metal* and 2 *wood* or *leather* and so on.
The player can then combine raw materials to get different components (like a wooden hilt or a leather hilt) and combine these components into a weapon.

This approach will allow you to have a **small defined set of reciepes** with quite **a lot outcomes**. You can then extend the system by addind some special reciepes (like hilt with a gem slot in it for extra elemental damage [*ruby = fire, onyx = earth and so on*]).

Hope this gets you started with the general idea, feel free to comment if you got questions.